# undefined method for imported module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller under `app/controllers`

```
require_relative '../../lib/bases_helper'

class BasesController < ApplicationController
  include BasesHelper

  def index
    BasesHelper.available_bases
  end
end
```

I am trying to use a method defined in another module under `lib`:

```
module BasesHelper
  def available_bases
    @bases = Base.all
  end
end
```

When I run my application and access the site, I get an error

```
undefined method `available_bases' for BasesHelper:Module
```

I can navigate to the method with my IDE by just clicking on its name. Why doesn't it resolve the method? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to add `BasesHelper` to use `available_bases` method. Just use method name like this

```
def index
  available_bases
end
```

As you imported `BasesHelper` module in your controller all methods of `BasesHelper` will be available in your controller. So you can use those method just by calling(without its module name) its name.

If you want to improve your code quality and follow rails conventions then please check Gerry's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although Junan Chakma [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246784/6136634) will work, i will advise against setting it up that way. Its better (and follows Rails conventions) to use a private method in your controller and use a callback (i.e. `before_action`); for example:

```
class BasesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_available_bases, only: [:index]

  def index
  end

  private
  def set_available_bases
    @bases = Base.all
  end
end
```

This will set up `@bases` instance variable to be used in your `index` action and `index.html.erb` view.

Comment: Wow, is this really the convention? I'm used (in Java) to take things out of the controller, which is what I was trying to do. This looks so much more complex. Good to know, thanks a lot!

Comment: @nprensen Yes, helpers are more commonly used for views, although doing it your way is not bad either; Rails actually likes _thin_ controllers. In fact i use that approach too for application wide methods, like sessions (and include the helper in application controller). For your specific example, since `available_bases` method will be used only by your `bases_controlller`, it makes sense to put it in the controller, most devs will expect it that way.

Answer (score -1):

It is because your method `available_bases` is an instance method of `BasesHelper`, not a class method. And you are calling it as if it were a class method.

If you want to use `available_bases` like a class method, `extend` the class instead of `include`-ing it.

```
class BasesController < ApplicationController
  extend BasesHelper
  ...
end
```